# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: how to properly define one-to-one relationship?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-one, cascading

I keep getting this exception when saving a compound object. Still cannot figre out how to overcome it..
Here is my mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store_house")
public class StoreHouse implements Serializable {

    // constructors

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="ING_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
    private double quantity;
}

// getters and setters
```

Here is DAO method where I get this exception:

```
    @Override
    public void insert(StoreHouse sh) {
         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(sh);
    }
```

Here is my test calss:

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/test-context.xml", "/test-data.xml"})
public class StoreHouseDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StoreHouseDAO storeHouseDAO;

    @Autowired
    private StoreHouse expectedStoreHouse;

    @Test
    public void itShouldPerformCRUDSmoothly() {
            // CREATE
            storeHouseDAO.insert(expectedStoreHouse);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
            // READ
            StoreHouse actualStoreHouse = storeHouseDAO.getByIngredient(expectedStoreHouse.getIngredient());
            assertEquals(actualStoreHouse.getIngredient().getId(), expectedStoreHouse.getIngredient().getId());
            // DELETE
            storeHouseDAO.delete(expectedStoreHouse);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
            StoreHouse emptyStoreHouse = storeHouseDAO.getByIngredient(expectedStoreHouse.getIngredient());
            assertNull(emptyStoreHouse);
    }
}
```

The fragment of defined test data:

```
   <bean id="expectedIngredient" class="com.restaurant.model.Ingredient">
        <property name="name" value="TestIngredient"/>
        <property name="unit" value="expectedUnit"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="expectedStoreHouse" class="com.restaurant.model.StoreHouse">
        <property name="ingredient" ref="expectedIngredient"/>
        <property name="quantity" value="10"/>
    </bean>
```

I feel like I botched when defining Cascading here.. But could you help me to correct it?

Comment: As you defined @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL}) your expectedIngredient will be deleted along with expectedStoreHouse. So you can't call expectedStoreHouse.getIngredient() after removing StoreHouse. You should exclude delete cascade type, or change unit test.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I commented Delete section in the test and got the same issue((. Logs show that insert method fails and doesn't actually insert Ingredient in the first place: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: com.restaurant.model.Ingredient. So the issue hides somehere else, perhaps in Cascade maping, it simply doesn't work as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work at the cost of simplifying the model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store_house")
public class StoreHouse implements Serializable {

    // constructors

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "SH_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="ING_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
    private double quantity;

    // getters and setters
    }
```

It actually requieres a separate id field, so I created it. And it statred to work smoothly. Will probably go with it as no other solutions were found.